# Visualizing high-dimensional sphere packing

Tags: visualization

I'm looking for an elegant way to visualize the following problem -- [allegedly](http://thenullhypodermic.blogspot.com/2019/12/high-dimensional-weirdness.html), if you put $2^d$ spheres in the corners of the $d$-dimensional cube and inscribe a sphere in the center, for $d>9$, the inscribed sphere will "poke out" from the sides of the cube. It would be neat to see what that looks like.

[image]

Comment: I think there is no way to  visualize it at all.  That's life.

Comment: We can use d-spaces and project the d-dimensional object to three dimension

Comment: @cvgmt: Let us consider two non-parallel straight lines in $\mathbb R^3$ which do not intersect and their projection onto a plane in general position. We will see two intersecting straight lines.

Comment: @user64494 Project the 3D object to 2D for EVERY direction,just as we use the 2D computer screen to display 3D object.

Comment: @cvgmt: "Project the 3D object to 2D for EVERY direction" is impossible to realize.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: Reminder of [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288221/how-to-combine-maximize-with-asymptotic-for-operatornameargmax-t-frac-sin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up coming back to this problem to visualize the section going through opposing edges of the (hyper)cube

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
d = 2; (* true dimension *)

norm2[vec_] = Total[vec*vec];

visualize[d_] := Module[{},
   (* vec1,vec2 determine the plane of our section *)
   vec1 = {1}~Join~ConstantArray[0, d - 1];
   vec2 = Normalize[{0}~Join~ConstantArray[1, d - 1]];
   mat = {vec1, vec2};
   
   a = 1;
   
   as = ConstantArray[a, d - 1];
   zeros = ConstantArray[0, d];
   
   (* Radius of inscribed sphere *)
   R = a (Sqrt[d] - 1);
   
   (* Corner spheres passing through the section *)
   c1 = {-a}~Join~as;
   c2 = {a}~Join~as;
   c3 = {-a}~Join~(-as);
   c4 = {a}~Join~(-as);
   
   sphere[center_, radius_] := 
    norm2[{x, y} . mat - center] <= radius^2;
   cornerSpheres = sphere[#, a] & /@ {c1, c2, c3, c4};
   centerSphere = sphere[zeros, R];
   
   spherePlot = 
    RegionPlot @@ {{centerSphere}~Join~
       cornerSpheres, {x, -Sqrt[a^2 d] - a, 
       Sqrt[a^2 d] + a}, {y, -Sqrt[a^2 d] - a, Sqrt[a^2 d] + a}, 
      AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> False};
   
   {c1, c2, c3, c4} = 
    Tuples[{{-2 a, 2 a}, {-2 a Sqrt[d - 1], 2 a Sqrt[d - 1]}}];
   cubePlot = Graphics[Line[{c1, c2, c4, c3, c1}]];
   
   Show[spherePlot, cubePlot, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2 a Sqrt[d - 1], 
       2 a Sqrt[d - 1]}, {-2 a Sqrt[d - 1], 2 a Sqrt[d - 1]}}]
   ];

pics = Table[visualize[d], {d, 2, 10}];
grid = Partition[pics, 3];
GraphicsGrid[grid, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

In high-dimensions, the corners of the cube are much more pointy, there's much more slack left over between packed sphere and edges. For $d=10$, the you can see that center inscribed sphere sticks out of the cube sides.

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/sphere-scratch.nb)