# How to combine Maximize with Asymptotic for $\operatorname{argmax}_t \frac{\sin (t) \sin ((n+1) t) \csc (n t)}{\pi }?$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Can anyone see a trick to get large-$n$ formula for the maximum for the following for integer $n>0$ and $t\in \left( 0, \frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)$?

$$\frac{\sin (t) \sin ((n+1) t) \csc (n t)}{\pi }$$

Ideally I could use asymptotic + maximize, but that returns unevaluated

```
Asymptotic[
 Maximize[{(Csc[n t] Sin[t] Sin[(1 + n) t])/\[Pi], 
   0 < t < Pi/(n + 1)}, t], n -> \[Infinity]]
```

Plotting on log-log plot it appears to approach power law

```
getVal[n_] := 
  First@Maximize[{(Csc[n t] Sin[t] Sin[(1 + n) t])/\[Pi], 
      0 < t < Pi/(n + 1)}, t];
ListPlot[Table[getVal[n], {n, 1, 6}], 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]
```

[image]

Background: this is weighted spectral density of a product of $n$ independent Gaussian matrices, ie `getVal[1]` is equivalent to `Maximize[x PDF[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1], x], x]`

Comment: Honestly this reads like a math question more than a Mathematica one.

Comment: This terrifies me. `f=Map[First,Table[Maximize[{Sin[t]Sin[(n+1)t]Csc[n t]/Pi,0<t<Pi/(n+1)} ,t],{n,1,60}]//N]; g=Transpose[{Range[60],f}]; h=Fit[g,{1,1/x^.75},x]; Show[ListPlot[g,PlotRange->All],Plot[h,{x,1,60},PlotRange->All]]` Use at your own risk ;}

Comment: @Bill Why the terror?

Comment: @JimB "large-n" when we have no idea how big his n is going to be. Didn't spend the time and effort to see if it was possible to derive an exact analytic solution. Tried 10 times as many data points as he did and fiddled with the exponent to eyeball what looks like  an ok fit for those points. Turning him loose with this and have no idea what he is about to do with this. I try to be MUCH more careful than that, and even then ask people to carefully check every detail to see if they can find and fix my mistakes. That is all.

Comment: @Bill Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @JimB I looked at the residuals out to n==240. They are very small. That and the graph was what fooled me into believing I had chosen a good enough and perhaps even the correct model. But they are not normally distributed about zero. So I did not choose the correct model. Fortunately there is an answer and hopefully it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical case is as follows.

```
n = 26; Plot[(Csc[n t] Sin[t] Sin[(1 + n) t])/Pi, {t, 0, Pi/(n + 1)}]
```

[image]

We see the maximum of the differentiable in $t$ function under consideration
is reached near $t=\frac \pi {n+1}$. In view of it we substitute `t -> Pi/(n + 1) - a`  in
its derivative and expand the derivative by powers of `a` near zero.

```
ClearAll[n];Series[D[(Csc[n t] Sin[t] Sin[(1 + n) t])/Pi, t] /. 
t -> Pi/(n + 1) - a, {a, 0, 1}] // Normal
```

> `-(((1 + n) Csc[(n \[Pi])/(1 + n)] Sin[\[Pi]/( 1 + n)])/\[Pi]) - (1/\[Pi]) 2 a (-Cos[\[Pi]/(1 + n)] Csc[(n \[Pi])/(1 + n)] -  n Cos[\[Pi]/(1 + n)] Csc[(n \[Pi])/(1 + n)] +  n Cot[(n \[Pi])/(1 + n)] Csc[(n \[Pi])/(1 + n)] Sin[\[Pi]/( 1 + n)] +  n^2 Cot[(n \[Pi])/(1 + n)] Csc[(n \[Pi])/(1 + n)] Sin[\[Pi]/( 1 + n)])`

(`{a, 0, 2}` does not make things better.) Then we equate the above to zero and solve in `a`.

```
sol=Solve[% == 0, a]
```

> `{{a -> Sin[\[Pi]/(1 + n)]/( 2 (Cos[\[Pi]/(1 + n)] -  n Cot[(n \[Pi])/(1 + n)] Sin[\[Pi]/(1 + n)]))}}`

We are interested in the maximum value so we substitute that value of `a` in the function.

```
((Csc[n t] Sin[t] Sin[(1 + n) t])/Pi /. t -> Pi/(n + 1) - a) /. sol
```

> `{(1/\[Pi]) Csc[n (\[Pi]/(1 + n) - Sin[\[Pi]/(1 + n)]/( 2 (Cos[\[Pi]/(1 + n)] -  n Cot[(n \[Pi])/(1 + n)] Sin[\[Pi]/(1 + n)])))] Sin[\[Pi]/( 1 + n) - Sin[\[Pi]/(1 + n)]/( 2 (Cos[\[Pi]/(1 + n)] -  n Cot[(n \[Pi])/(1 + n)] Sin[\[Pi]/(1 + n)]))] Sin[(1 +  n) (\[Pi]/(1 + n) - Sin[\[Pi]/(1 + n)]/( 2 (Cos[\[Pi]/(1 + n)] -  n Cot[(n \[Pi])/(1 + n)] Sin[\[Pi]/(1 + n)])))]}`

At last, in order to find the asymptotic,

```
Series[%, {n, Infinity, 2}]
```

> `{1/(3 n)-7/(18 n^2)+O[1/n]^3}`

Calculations confirm the exponent `-1`.

```
getVal[n_] := First@NMaximize[{(Csc[n t] Sin[t] Sin[(1 + n) t])/\[Pi],
 0 < t < Pi/(n + 1)}, t];Table[Log[getVal[n]]/Log[n], {n, 200, 260}]
```

> `{-1.02648, -1.02639, ... , -1.02222, -1.02217}`

Addition. Here is my successful attempt. Let us write down $\sin((n+1)t)=\sin(nt)\cos(t)+\cos(nt)\sin(t)$. Because $t\in \left[0,\frac \pi {n+1}\right]$ and $n$ tends to $\infty$, I replace $\sin(t)$ by $t$ and $\cos(t)$ by $1- \frac  {t^2} 2$. It's summer now and I'm not in the mood to give error estimates. Let us look at a typical case

```
n = 26; Plot[{(Sin[n*t]*(1 - t^2/2) + Cos[n*t]*t)*t*Csc[n*t]/Pi, 
(Sin[t]* Csc[n t] Sin[(1 + n) t])/\[Pi]}, {t, 0, Pi/n}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Blue, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

It is convenient to make a replacement

```
ClearAll[n]; (Sin[n*t]*(1 - t^2/2) + Cos[n*t]*t)*t*Csc[n*t]/Pi /. t -> x/n
```

> `(x Csc[x] ((x Cos[x])/n + (1 - x^2/(2 n^2)) Sin[x]))/(n \[Pi])`

Now we expand it around `Pi`

```
b = Series[(x Csc[x] ((x Cos[x])/n + (1 - x^2/(2 n^2)) Sin[x]))/(n*Pi), {x, Pi, 4}] // Normal
```

> `(4 n + 2 n^2 - \[Pi]^2)/(2 n^3) + \[Pi]/( n^2 (-\[Pi] + x)) + ((6 n + 6 n^2 - 9 \[Pi]^2 -  2 n \[Pi]^2) (-\[Pi] + x))/( 6 n^3 \[Pi]) + ((-9 - 4 n) (-\[Pi] + x)^2)/( 6 n^3) + ((-45 - 30 n - 2 n \[Pi]^2) (-\[Pi] + x)^3)/( 90 n^3 \[Pi]) - (2 (-\[Pi] + x)^4)/(45 n^2)`

I repeat it's summer now and I'm not in the mood to give error estimates.

```
Maximize[{b, x >= Pi/2 && x <= Pi && n >= 35}, x] // First
```

produces a huge result in terms of a `Root` of a polynomial of 5-th degree. Now

```
Series[%, {n, Infinity, 1}]
```

> `1/n+O[1/n]^(3/2)`

Calculations confirm it by

```
getVal[n_] := First@NMaximize[{(Csc[n t] Sin[t] Sin[(1 + n) t])/\[Pi], 
0 < t < Pi/(n + 1)}, t]; Table[getVal[n]*n, {n, 3000000, 3000020}]
```

> `{0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846,  0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846,  0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846, 0.998846,  0.998846}`

Moreover, the result of

```
getVal[n_] := First@NMaximize[{(Csc[n t] Sin[t] Sin[(1 + n) t])/\[Pi],  0 < t < Pi/(n + 1)}, t]; 
Table[(getVal[n] - 1/n)*n^(3/2), {n, 3000000, 5000000, 500000}]
```

> `{-1.99884, -1.99893, -1.99902, -1.99906, -1.99911}`

confirms $O(n^{-3/2}),\,n\to \infty.$

Comment: At first glance, the approximation error has the order $O(n^{-3}),\, n \to \infty.$