# Getting rid of "too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may \ be lost" messages in plot

Tags: plotting

In the plot below I'm only using exact numbers, yet I get warnings about precision being lost, is there another setting I'm missing to get an accurate plot?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
nmax = 200;
x[t_] := Sin[(n + 1) t]^(n + 1)/(Sin[t] Sin[n t]^n);
y[t_] := (Sin[t]^2 Sin[n t]^(n - 1))/(\[Pi] Sin[(n + 1) t]^n) x[t];

scale[a_] := 
  a*Pi/(n + 1); (* horizontal scaling, since t in 0..Pi/(n+1) *)
xlim = (1 + 1/n)^
   n (1 + n);  (* vertical scaling, Assuming[{n>1},Limit[x[t],t->0]] *)

xScaled[t_] := x[scale[t]]/xlim;
yScaled[t_] := y[scale[t]]*xlim;


parametric0 = 
 Block[{n = nmax}, 
  ParametricPlot @@ {{xScaled[t], yScaled[t]}, {t, 0, 90/100}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, 
    PlotLabel -> "Eigenvalue density for product of random matrices", 
    PlotStyle -> {Bold}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
    PlotLegends -> {"n=100"}}]
```

Comment: Add `// Quiet` to the end of `ParametricPlot`.  That gets rid of the message (what you have in the title).  But it doesn't mean the one should ignore the message.  Or change `{t, 0, 90/100}` to`{t, 1/100, 90/100}`.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: Did you pay your attention to my answer to [the question of you](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288221/how-to-combine-maximize-with-asymptotic-for-operatornameargmax-t-frac-sin/288229#288229)?