# Explicitly specifying objects in Graphics3D to use default color?

Tags: graphics3d

How do I explicitly specify the directive that's used to color objects in Graphics3D?

IE, in the graphics below, I wanted last sphere and the first sphere to have the same colors, `Automatic` doesn't see to be a thing

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0,0,0}], Red, Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, 1], Automatic, Sphere[{2, 0, 0}, 1]}]
```

Comment: Reminder of [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288221/how-to-combine-maximize-with-asymptotic-for-operatornameargmax-t-frac-sin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}], {Red, Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, 1]}, Sphere[{2, 0, 0}, 1]}]
```

**EDIT:**

By the way the default color is `White`.

So you can do it also like this (replacing your `Automatic` with `White`):

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0,0,0}], Red, Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, 1], White, Sphere[{2, 0, 0}, 1]}]
```